python PyQt6 threading асинхронность
Здравствуйте в приложении есть дополнительный поток (из threading). В дополнительном потоке генерируется строка, которую необходимо записать в QTextBrowser. Если делать это напрямую из дополнительного потока, то приложение закрывается ( Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Необходимо добавить код, который вызывает ошибку. А в общем случае лучше использовать поток QThread, в котором будет жить наследник QObject, который в нужный момент отправляет строку сигналом.

Константин, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.
